# Flutter auto-update app when a new version is released

Tags: flutter

I wonder how to make my application (which is already published on play-store and app-store) updates automatically when a new version is released.
I have found some packages that support similar thing like: https://pub.dev/packages/new_version and https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader but the issue is that all these packages display a dialog when a new version is detected. But I am asking about making it completely automatic without any dialogs appearing.
I also knew about https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config but it doesn't answer my question about releasing new version.
I see this feature in a lot of apps but I don't know how it's made in flutter.

Comment: Have you tried this plugin ? https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update however its's only for android in iOS it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't auto-update.
Auto-update strategy depends on user settings
You can only ask user for update

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that the Application gets automatically downloaded and installed. Both ways are also not allowed from the AppStore and PlayStore Agreements.